# EF6 Conflicting changes detected on save

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a parent/child hierarchy of which I want to insert a new parent into a DbContext and have it automatically persist the child objects.

Every time I all SaveChanges on DbContext EF is throwing an exception of

> Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert
>   multiple entities with the same key.

I understand the error as the Child object doesn't have a Identity column.

Models are as follows:

```
public class Parent
{
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
     public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping for the Child object below::

```
public class ChildMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Child>
{
   this.HasKey(p => p.ParentId);
   this.Property(p => p.ParentId)
       .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

   this.HasRequired(t => t.Parent)
       .WithMany(t => t.Children)
       .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentId);
}
```

The models were generated using EF Power tools as we are following DB-First design.

Is there a way saving the graph instead of saving the parent first then child?

Comment: Did you define a primary key?

Comment: If a parent can have multiple childs, you can't have ParentId as the primary key.

Comment: The primary key is the foreign key (ParentId). There's no Identity column though

Comment: You cannot have multiple childs with the same primary key. It has to be unique. That's why you have the conflict.

Comment: I missed something on the model and its working fine now. Thanks for the help

Comment: You missed what? I have the same problem, and your answer is far from helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, which was resolved by removing unnecessary FK associations from the Model. For some reason, these weren't removed when updating the model from the database.

To do this, I simply found the association in the Entity Designer, removed it, and re-updated the model from the database.

It can also be caused by having invalid relationship multiplicities on a particular column, i.e. a 0..1 - 1 relationship, rather than * - 1. Create a new Entity Diagram under the Model Browser and add the tables you're investigating (and their related tables), and you'll be able to easily see (and change) the multiplicities.